# Classifieds website structure based on category - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to build a classified website with Worpdress, but I have doubts about the structure.
The categories would be for example:
cars, computers, telephones, pets.
Then there would be the cities: Miami, New York ..
And finally the tags: bmw, toyota, ibm

I want the structure to be as follows:
http://example.com//
Ex: http://example.com/cars/miami and list all ads that sell cars in Miami.
Ex: http://example.com/pets/newyork/ and list all ads that sell animals in New York

Wordpress allows me to use categories and subcategories:
Cars -> Miami
Cars -> New York
etc..
But if I create a subcategory for each city, when I want to create:
Pets -> Miami
Pets -> New York
Wordpress creates miami-2, newyork-2 as SLUG.
How could I make the structure as I described it at the beginning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Category base and Tag base are prefixes used in URLs for category and tag archives, which look like this:

example.net/category_base/category_name
 example.net/tag_base/tag_name
The default values for these are category and tag. You can change them, but you can't remove them from the URLs altogether.

Custom permalinks work on most systems without any problems, but there are still some conditions where problems occur.

Settings → Permalinks

[more information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)